# Unable to sync apple watch simulator with iPhone simulator for adding SSL certificates

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, apple-watch

I am trying to add some profile certificates to apple watch simulator.
First I added them into iPhone simulator it was successful.
Now I added profiles to apple watch simulator from iPhone simulator but I received a popup as "Apple watch is syncing" and this task never finishes.

Trying to add profiles on simulators.

How to fix this issue?
[image]

Comment: Please file a feedback request for this; it is likely a bug.

Comment: can you suggest me where I can request this.Already I raised a request in apple.developer.com.

Comment: Sure, go to https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/

Comment: already raised a query on that in apple assistant.But thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution on this? Can you share the thread you opened?